# Unable to Upload an Unlisted or a Private video using an Internal App created for the G Suite Domain

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-workspace

I want to upload an unlisted video in the YouTube using YouTube Data V3 API. Only users in our domain should be able to upload videos.

I have done following:

1. Created a Google Cloud Platform project and enabled YouTube API
2. Created OAuth2 credential for INTERNAL use.
3. Since it's an 'internal' use credential, we don't need to verify our App and there is no option to verify the App.
4. We used this credential to upload an Unlisted video to YouTube. It uploaded the video to YouTube successfully but created a Private video and not an Unlisted video.

The reason given to us is that you cannot upload an Unlisted or a Public video from an unverified App. But since it's an Internal App for our domain, there is no option to verify the App. Hence I believe we should be able to upload a Public or an Unlisted video from Internal App.

Please let us know if there is any way we can make this work.

Many thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

> We used this credential to upload an Unlisted video to YouTube. It uploaded the video to YouTube successfully but created a Private video and not an Unlisted video.

All videos uploaded by unverified apps are set private until the app has been verified then you will be able to set them to unlisted.

The thing is you have set your project to internal only which means that only those within your Gsuite domain should be able to see these videos. I dont understand why you would need them to be set unlisted.

Considering the following definitions:

> Private means only those you invite to view the video can view it

> Unlisted means your video will not come up in search results or on your channel either.  Only those who know the link can view it.  Its still Public.

Again considering that only verified apps can create public videos I hope this explains why you cant set them Unlisted.  If you really want them set unlisted instead of just private for the domain.   You will have to go though the long verification process.

Comment: As far as I understand, Internal App shall work same as Verified public App because there is no verification required. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Comment: "The thing is you have set your project to internal only which means that only those within your Gsuite domain should be able to see these videos." This is not correct. Internal Credentials mean only users in my domain can use those credentials. But that does not restrict users to create publicly available content. For example, using Internal Credentials, I can create a new publicly shared Google Spreadsheet. So using Internal Credentials, I should be able to upload a public or unlisted video on YouTube.

Comment: @DalmTo Can you please look into this? I think it's standard use case - Allowing your team members in your own domain to upload Unlisted or Public videos to YouTube using internal credentials.

Comment: Unlisted is still public its just not listed.  If you want to set them public you need to go though the verification process.   Domain members can upload private videos viewable by the members of the domain.   If you think other wise you might want to consider posting it as an issue.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B